# Creating Multiple Views in Nagios 4 Status Map

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have nagios set up to monitor our infrastructure across many different sites.  As our business grows it is becoming a bit unwieldy.  I have not discovered a way to set one node as the root and have it only show the children of that node.  We are monitoring hundreds of nodes per customer/geographic area, and our current set up is growing more and unwieldy by the day.

The nagios/map.html?host=all interface does not seem configurable.  Whatever I put after host= doesn't seem to have any effect on the result.

I am currently contemplating running different nagios instances on different ports, with a different port per root node that I would like to able monitor separately.  This is a long way from what I want to achieve though.

I guess this boils down is there a way to make map.html spit out a subset of your nodes that I have yet to discover?

Answer (score 1):

Nagios has always been somewhat limited in its means to 'graphically' view your systems, especially if you have a very large install - whereas statusmap.cgi looks like a giant plate of spaghetti.  The best solution I've seen in NagVis.  With it, you can create those customized map-like views.  [screenshots here](http://www.nagvis.org/screenshots)